# How to run a function when an app first loads

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a simple to-do list in Swift that will store the list as an array of Strings and then call it back from memory when the app loads.

I've got the following code:

```
var itemList = [String]()

func loadData() -> [String] {
    var arr = [String]()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("storedData") != nil {
        arr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("storedData")! as! [String]
    }
    else {
        arr = ["Nothing to do..."]
    }

    return arr
}

func saveData(arr: [String]) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arr, forKey: "storedData")
}
```

Where I'm getting stuck is in where to place the call to loadData(). This is an app that has two view controllers (one for the list, one for an add item setup), so if I place the loadData() call in viewDidLoad() for the main view controller, the array is called back in from memory (and over-written) every time I switch back to the main view controller.

Where is the best place to call this so that it will load once only, upon the app starting up?

Comment: put code in viewDidLoad then. It will be called only once when the viewController gets the memory.

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?

Comment: @Rohit When I put it in viewDidLoad, the loadData() function gets called every time I segue between the views. (I put a print function into viewDidLoad to test this and the text is printed with each segue). Is this happening because I've done something else wrong then?

Comment: @ZoffDino - how can I access applicationDidFinishLaunching? Is that a function of UIViewController?

Comment: It's part of the App Delegate. It's called once when the application has finished loading from XIB

Comment: Then put it into your mainViewController and check a flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the array is called back in from memory (and over-written) every time I switch back to the main view controller.

No. `viewDidLoad` only loads once, when the app starts. Only `viewWillApprear` and `viewDidAppear` get called everytime the viewcontroller changes.

Also you could make your code a bit more compact by using `if let`:

```
  if let storedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("storedData") as! [String]{
     arr = storedData
  }
```

But if you want to make sure to load this only once, you can put it in your `AppDelegate` file in your `applicationDidFinishWithOptions` method.

But you'd have to make a variable in your `AppDelegate` file which you can access from your viewController.

Comment: Ok cool I thought that this should be the case. Firstly, thanks for the suggestion for a more compact statement. I've got print("Loaded View") in viewDidLoad and the phrase prints every time I segue between view controllers. So it sounds like maybe I've got the app set up wrong if its calling viewDidLoad multiple times?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You could pack your code in your AppDelegate file.

Comment: Thanks @Christian - is it ok to do that? I'm really green here! I wasn't sure if it was ok to use the App delegate for more than just communicating between the views. Am I right in thinking I would need to instantiate the view controllers within the App Delegate?

Comment: @lordchancellor no. You just create a variable in AppDelegate outside of any function. Then inside the applicationDidFinish... Method you initialize that Variable. Later in your viewcontroller, you can access the AppDelegate variable.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad() only happens when the View Controller is first instantiated. If it is your root view controller you can have it in viewDidLoad().

The other goes, viewDidLoad > viewWillAppear > viewDidAppear. After the view is first loaded only the latter 2 methods are called whenever you navigate.

you can also always register for a **NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification** notification at the notification center

check it out here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification

Answer (score 0):

Use or overwrite respectively

```
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

of your application delegate. 
That is called only once upon application launch. 
See 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is called after the view for a single controller is first loaded. It shouldn't be called more than once for the life-cycle of a single viewController. Maybe it is possible that, if you are not calling "super.viewDidLoad()" in your own viewDidLoad method, then it may be called again? While you can generally assume that the rootViewController for an application is only created once, I think it's theoretically possible that it might be cleared out of memory by the app if required and then recreated again - so I would never assume it's only called once.

One thing you could do is just set a boolean (default false) to true whenever you load the data and then not call it again if the flag is already set to true.

Alternatively, it's a good idea to separate the data management from your viewControllers. A relatively simple solution would be to have a class called "AppData" say, which might be a singleton (so you can only ever have one instance of it) or a member of your AppDelegate. Then, in your app delegate's "applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, you could create the one instance of the AppData class and call the loadData method on it. This class would then live independently of whichever view is currently showing, and the current view could call methods on this object to load/save/update data as required.